# Resizing sprite causes null reference exceptions

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am building a minesweeper game that has a grid of tiles 10x13 (Pic 1).
In the Inspector each tile has been positioned on the X and Y axis (0 to 9 and 0 to 12).

I want to adjust the size of these tiles (Pic 2), however if I make any change I get the below error when the project loads.
*IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

And when I click on any tile I get the following error.
*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

[image: Standard Grid Layout]
[image: Adjusted size Layout]

This exception relates to the below code snipet that is written on the void Start

*IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

```
 // Register in Grid
         int x = (int)transform.position.x;
        int y = (int)transform.position.y;
        Playfield.elements[x, y] = this;
```

Whilst this exception relates to the below class.

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

```
    public class Playfield
{
    // The Grid itself
    public static int w = 10; // this is the width
    public static int h = 13; // this is the height
    public static Element[,] elements = new Element[w, h];

// Uncover all Mines
public static void uncoverMines()
{
    foreach (Element elem in elements)
        if (elem.mine) elem.loadTexture(0);
}
```

Sometimes tiles work sometimes not.
Is there an alternative way of setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's javascript? Looks like C# :)

The issue is visible on the screenshots you provided.

You cast `x` and `y` from gameobject's position to `int` and use them as indices for your array. But now, look at the second screenshot - after positioning/scaling, you have the element at `(-1.194, -0.635)`. When these values are cast to int you get `-1` and `0`. And guess what happens when trying to access the array with these values? *IndexOutOfRangeException*.

As we've already proven, the positions on scene are not corresponding to your array indices anymore, so some elements inside the array are most probably not initialized at all. When iterating `elements` and trying to access data from null element, it throws *NullReferenceException*.

How to fix it? You should not depend on scene positions to register your elements. I'd reverse the logic: create a prefab for element object and a script that fills the board with objects instantiated from this prefab. Define your array there and add each element to it when instantiating. Of course you'd need to define additional properties, like elements offset and starting position, for everything to appear properly. But it would also give you flexibility to simply customize the board dimensions.